# swift physicsbody is not matching up to image size

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I have two nodes, player and platfrom. Both have a physicsBody around them. My player is still and the platform scroll by an SkAction. when the player reaches about half-way on top of the platform it falls threw it.

```
player.physicsBody=SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:player.frame.size)
player.physicsBody?.isDynamic=true
player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation=false
player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity=true

platform.physicsBody=SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:platfrom.frame.size)
platform.physicsBody?.isDynamic=false
```

the platfrom set up is.

```
 plat.size=CGSize(width:(self.frame.width)*2,height:(self.frame.height)/3)
 plat.anchorPoint=CGPoint(x:0,y:0)
 plat.position=CGPoint(x:0,y:0)
 plat.zPosition = 2
 addChild(platform)
```

I tried using this instead but player still falls down

```
plat.physicsBody=SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:CGSize(width:platform.width,
height: platform.frame.height))
```

I want the nodes to act like a solid object, in that they don't overlap each other when the player moves. Also it there an alternative method I can use. I don't really like working with physics.

Comment: So what does happen with your current code?

Comment: Try setting `view.showsPhysics = true` in `didMove` to display an outline of the physics bodies in the scene.

Comment: Thanks! apparently physicsBody doesn't adhere to anchorPoint changes. @0x141E

Comment: @CindySmith Have you tried with SKPhysicsBody init(edgeLoopFrom rect: platform.frame) for your plat ?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano yes. I solved it, by changing the ankorpoints.

Comment: @CindySmith well, task solved. Good luck with your project.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate to working with physics is to use the recently added to iOS 10 `SKTilemapNode` to create the background. Each tile can be tagged with data to indicate if the tile is ground or not. You then focus on how the player moves relative to the tiles. There are currently not a lot of examples to show this working, the [WWDC 2016: What's new in SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/610/) shows this briefly. Other resources include a [top down](https://www.raywenderlich.com/137216/whats-new-spritekit-ios-10-look-tile-maps) example which shows at least how to build the background tilemap and some [background info](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2013/08/physics-engine-platformer-terrible-idea/) on why physics engines don't provide the best experience for platformers. [Kenney's](http://kenney.nl/assets?q=2d) is a good source of tiles for platformer artwork.